# How to merge contents of untracked directory to root of other branch

Tags: git, github, merge, github-pages

For my GitHub pages I use a static site generator. The source of the site lives in the `<source>` branch and it generates the html files in the `_site` directory.
The `<master>` branch is used to show the actual website and should contain the generated html files at the root level.

Since I don't want the `_site` directory and it's contents to be part of my `<source>` branch I've ignored the `_site` directory (by putting `_site` in my `.gitignore`).

Now the question I have is how can I merge the untracked contents of the `_site` directory of the `<source>` branch to the root of the `<master>` branch?

**Update**
The main problem seems to that Git needs anything you want to merge to be tracked (rightfully so ;)), but I don't want to track the generated files in my `<source>` branch.
The only workarounds I can come up with use at least 1 temporary branch that can be deleted afterwards. Using git subtree split from a temporary branch into another temporary branch seems to be the cleanest option.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

This is what I came up with:

```
# Checkout branch <temp1> carrying over the current working
# directory including ignored/untracked files
git checkout -b temp1

# Add _site to staging ignoring .gitignore and commit
git add -f _site/
git commit -m "irrelevant commitmessage"

# Subtree split _site to <temp2> branch (root of branch)
git subtree --prefix=_site/ split -b temp2

# Checkout master and merge <temp2>
git checkout master
git merge --squash temp2
git commit -m "commitmessage"

# Remove <temp1> and <temp2> branches and push
```

Comment: one simple approach, could just be `checkout master` and since that branch will not have the .gitignore entry, it will show all the changed files under site as new files or new changes. Can you try that? It's not a merge, but probably it will do the trick.

Comment: @bitoiu That is the easiest way to get unstaged/untracked files to another branch but they remain in their original location (ie the `<_site>` folder) and not in the root of the branch.

Since I want to merge **only** the generated files to the `<master>` branch (to keep the changes/diffs between "released" versions of the site) I would need to find a way to get the files from `_site` to the root of the branch and only add these files to the commit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git map directory to branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097489/git-map-directory-to-branch)

Answer (score 0):

If there's better solutions to this problem, I'll welcome them, but given that you want to do a kind of merge, which is really not one, I can only suggest you create a post-commit script or a bash/perl/python script that does the following:

1. if not on "source" branch (could be any condition) quit
2. create another branch like temp001
3. on that branch copy all the contents
4. copy from _site to root
5. checkout master merge temp001
6. quit (my advice)

Now confirm your changes and commit/push. You can do this on the last step but I wouldn't do so in the first try runs.

This is the best I can suggest.

Comment: Using a script (post commit or post push) is a good suggestion, I will definitely do that.

Concerning the actual merge, see my edit to the question, what do you think about my current solution using a <temp1> branch and git subtree split?

Comment: not the best person to comment on subtrees. I've had a not so good experience with sub modules and never again.

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure if you'll find a built in solution in git for your particular problem. Keep this, and change it if it becomes an inconvenience.