# Git map directory to branch

Tags: git

I have repository `blog`:

```
blog
├─ master
│  └─ _site
│     └─ more folders
│
└─ gh-pages
```

I would like to map `master:_site/` to the branch `gh-pages`. How would I do this using `git`?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `gh-pages` branch to the primary repository as a submodule.  Something like this:

```
cd blog
git submodule add -b gh-pages <my-repository-url> master/_site
```

This assumes that the directory `master/_site` does not already exist.  You will want to thoroughly read and understand the [submodules section of the Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).  In particular, when you commit changes inside of your `_site` directory, the process will generally be:

```
cd master/_site
...edit some file...
git add some_file
git commit -m 'edit all the things'
cd ..
git commit -m 'edited some files' _site
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is fully paranoid:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ghpages=`git rev-parse -q --verify gh-pages`; then
        # there's already a branch, don't double-commit a tree
        committed=`git rev-parse -q --verify gh-pages^{tree}`
        current=`git rev-parse -q --verify master:_site`
        test x$current = x$committed && exit
fi
if commit=`git commit-tree ${ghpages:+-p $ghpages} -m 'updating gh-pages' master:_site`; then do
        git update-ref refs/heads/gh-pages $commit
fi
```

To hardwire the mapping as requested, put that in `.git/hooks/post-commit` and `chmod +x` it.

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Comment: `rev-parse` turns any reference into a SHA. You can assign the output of a command to a variable and test its return code as I do in the `if`s, first checking for a `gh-pages` ref.  The body of that exits if `the currently-committed `gh-pages` tree is also the currently-committed tree at `master:_site`.  The `commit-tree` includes a parent parameter if there's a gh-pages branch to extend (the `:+` syntax says "substitute the7 following if the tested variable isn't empty), and the update-ref does exactly what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

From the wide variety of intimidating ways to perform this, I'd secretly (?) do this one for me (starting from the root of the local copy in the branch master):

```
git checkout gh-pages
git checkout master -- _site/
mv _site/* .
rm -rf _site
```

Then commit and push changes:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Copied site from master"
git push origin gh-pages
```

Comment: If you have `_site` in `_site` both will get deleted.

Comment: Yes. I'd secretly fail.

Comment: Just rename `_site/_site' temporarily, don't need to worry about `_site/_site/_site'.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to initialize a git repository in `_site`.

```
cd blog

# populates _site
jekyll build
cd _site

# create git repository, add files and push
git init
git checkout -b gh-pages
git commit -am "message"
git remote add git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
git push origin gh-pages
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to current directory, which you want to map to remote master, and then type below.

1. git clone yourCloneURL
2. copy ".git" folder from cloned dir to current direcotry

   cp yourClonedFolder/.git .
3. delete clone folder

   rm -rf yourClonedFolder
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "Initial Commit"
6. git push origin master

Comment: Doesn't this just merge two repos destroying the history of the original?

Comment: No. It won't merge with old. You are replacing old git with new git. You will loose old git data. This should be used when you need to bring back your git url repository state to existing git folder.