# Git pull specific folder (actually only download that folder)

Tags: git, github, workflow

So I've been trying to find an acceptable deploy solution for my team and our projects. I read a ton of How To's but at the end of the day, I just want to push to the master branch on github and have the site updated.

So to do that, I thought I'd do this:

1. create a web hook on github that notifies our server when the master branch recieves a `push`
2. make the server `pull` from our github repo's master branch

Now this is the problem: our repositories include a lot of building and source files. Gulp, Sass, all that fun stuff. It's only one specific folder (`dist` in our case) that actually serves the web app (html, css, js, php, ect).

So I'm searching for a way that the automatic `pull` of the github repo from our server only ever downloads the `/dist` folder into it's `/public_html` folder.

I looked at `git config core.sparsecheckout true` but it seems that this will download the whole repo and just hides the other files from the view.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull anything with a ref. The thing to do is to make a branch that tracks only that subtree, github's `gh-pages` is a very common example of this.  [Here's a worked example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097489/git-map-directory-to-branch), that shows how to use the plumbing to do gruntwork with already-committed content like this, you can put your webhook on just the `gh-pages` branch or whatever you decide to name it.