# Is it possible to replace the tree of a git branch without first checking it out?

Tags: git, github, doxygen

For pages on [github.io](http://github.io), it is common to use a branch called `gh-pages` on the main repository to publish a website associated with a particular repository.

In my current project, I perform the following steps to update my documentation which is hosted on [github.io](http://github.io).

1. Build API documentation on the main branch using Doxygen.
2. Move the `html` directory to a temporary directory.
3. Checkout the `gh-pages` branch.
4. Copy the contents of the temporary directory to the project directory.
5. `git commit` and `git push` the `gh-pages` branch.
6. Checkout `master` branch again.

**Is it possible to commit the contents of the `html` directory to the `gh-pages` branch in a single step?**

Note that I prefer not to add the contents of the `html` directory to the `master` branch because it is generated content rather than source.

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668886/git-copy-all-files-in-a-directory-from-another-branch) but they do not appear to solve this problem.

This is not actually a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933044/commit-a-file-to-a-different-branch-without-checkout) because this question concerns whole-tree replacement rather than adding a single file, and I believe the former operation can be done in a cleaner way than the latter.

Comment: I originally thought my question was a duplicate of the other one, but I realized that I'm trying to do whole-tree-replacement, which feels different enough to warrant a new answer, which I will post myself when this question gets re-opened.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23097670/1290731), shows how to do it if you _are_ committing the tree to master.  Extending that to a commit of a tree you haven't already committed means learning how to use `git write-tree` and `git read-tree` as well.

Comment: @jthill, I spent the last couple days learning to use `git write-tree` and `git read-tree`. :)

Comment: @jthill, But I think my script is not quite as safe as yours yet, because I haven't made sure there are no double-commits of the same tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the following script to avoid the use of an additional working directory, although @axiac's answer is a valid way to solve this problem.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# This script will take a directory and replace the contents of a non-current
# branch with it.
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo \
    "Usage:  replace-branch <top level directory> <branchname> <commit message>"
    exit
fi

root="$1"
branch="$2"
msg="$3"

# First check if the index is polluted, since we will be using it.
save=HEAD
indexDiverges=$(git diff-index --cached  $(git rev-parse HEAD))
if [[ -n "$indexDiverges" ]]; then
    save=$(git write-tree)
fi

# Create a new index
git read-tree --empty
GIT_WORK_TREE=$root git add .

# Check whether the index is actually different from the target.
isDuplicateCommit=$(git diff-index --cached  $(git rev-parse $branch))
if [[ ! -n "$isDuplicateCommit" ]]; then
    echo "The branch already matches the state we are trying to commit!"
    git read-tree $save
    exit
fi

# Write the index out to a new tree
tree=$(git write-tree)

# Commit with the given commit message to the other branch
commithash=$(echo "$msg" | git commit-tree $tree -p $(git rev-parse $branch))

# Move the branch pointer.
git update-ref $(git show-ref --heads "$branch"  | awk '{print $2}') \
    "$commithash"

# Restore the index to its previous state
git read-tree $save
```

I have also decided to upgrade this a bit and put it on [GitHub](https://github.com/hq6/git-replace-branch) with example usage.

Comment: Rather than refuse to continue, you could just `save=$(git write-tree)` and then read-tree that rather than HEAD at the end.

Comment: @jthill, Thanks for the suggestion. I'm adding that as well as the duplicate-tree check.

Answer (score 1):

Clone your remote repo again in a new local repo.
Checkout the branch `gh_pages` in this new repository.

Use the repo you already have for development, the same way you are using it now.

Build the API documentation on the main branch of the development repository using Doxygen as you do now. If possible, configure the process to produce the output in the directory where the second local repo is stored. Otherwise move the generated documentation to the second local repo after it is created.

Run `git add .; git commit; git push` in the second repository (the documentation repo).

Repeat the last two steps every time it's needed.

Comment: You can also use `git worktree`: https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows

Comment: @TavianBarnes Indeed. Develop the idea to an answer. It's better than mine.